# How to save boot log from failed boot?

Tags: boot, log, dmesg

I know I can run `dmesg` to look at boot errors. However, my system is failing to boot right now. It hangs indefinitely while trying to initialize hard drives. However, I can boot up into safe mode.

When I boot up in safe mode and look at `dmesg` it does not contain old boot messages. It just contains the boot messages from the current boot-up into safe mode.

How do I save the `dmesg` log (or any log for that matter) during the failed boot process so that I can view it when I log in to diagnose via save mode?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not at a Ubuntu pc right now, but I'm trying to help out.

If I'm not mistaken boot logging is disabled by default.

In  /etc/default/bootlogd set

```
BOOTLOGD_ENABLE=Yes
```

Now, each boot entries in /var/log/boot will be created in a file that's readable by root (so sudo is needed). If I'm not mistaken this log is rotated so you'll have older versions.

If that won't work or you're not in /etc/sudoers, you can also try to boot with a bootable usbdrive and check the bootlog after a failed boot or boot into safe mode and redirect dmesg into a file using the output redirection operator:

```
dmesg > bootmessages$(date +%Y%m%d).bak
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `journalctl` to look at previous boot logs, thusly:

```
journalctl -b -1 -e
```

will look at the previous boot. By varying the number, you can see earlier boot logs. Also `journalctl --list-boots` is handy to show when boot #N took place.

You can also ask `journalctl` about the disk's log messages:

```
jounalctl /dev/sda
```

Comment: From the man page: "-0 is the last boot, -1 the boot before last".

Comment: This shows the previous SUCCESSFUL boot, not a failed one.